# html5 animation integration in magento like wordpress

Tags: magento-1.9

in wordpress i integrate my adobe edge file (.oam) with a simple plugin

this plugin allow me add .oam file like other image, this plugin is called

https://github.com/ekino/wp-oam-renderer

exist something like this for magento or is possible translate this plugin?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about HTML5. You would probably have more luck on stackoverflow

Comment: what is stackoverflow? thanks for reply!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/ is the general development question site. There will be a lot more experts on HTML5 there.

Comment: oh thanks i try it! i thinks is so easy but i'm a graphic and i cant!

Comment: Did you take a look at https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/how-to/integrate-edge-animate.html by the way? seems to have some manuals

Comment: yea but i need to integrate in magento....no problem with other cms because someone have studied a method, for magento i cannot understand how to load this simple image on my page....only animated images, little interactivity....i don't understand how to put code in the header of my page, magento is hard for me

Comment: Ok, please update your question with how you do it on other CMS's and I'll try and translate that to Magento :)

Comment: okkkk for wordpress i use this plugin

Comment: WP Edge Animate OAM Renderer

Comment: https://github.com/ekino/wp-oam-renderer

Comment: this allow me to add .oam file like image and after i recall it with a <div>

Comment: Hm ok, I'll take a look somewhere today and report back

Comment: i change the text of the topic i hope is right

Answer (score 0):

It is not as simple to add like an image, as for images the cms parts only handles the url (the src= attribute of the image tag)

What you need is to implement a widget which generates the html output.

this links will hopefully help you on how to create a widget for magento.

- http://magentoexpertforum.com/showthread.php/12562-Develop-a-Magento-Widget-in-Easiest-way
- http://inchoo.net/magento/blank-magento-widget-to-get-you-started-with-magento-widget-development/
- http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#cms/widgets.html
- [How to structure Ajax module/widget](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17831/how-to-structure-ajax-module-widget)
- [what is widget in magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40324/what-is-widget-in-magento/40327#40327)

but be carefully, some of this links are a bit older, there may be some changes in newer versions oo how to do it.